# How to do these android buttons

Tags: android, button, layout

I'm starting with material layout and wanted to know how do I make this buttons. Especially the two with the tiny line in between

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCnwC.png)

Thanks

Comment: AppCompat and create a button theme with Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless(.Colored) and design it to whatever you want in styles.xml

Comment: if I put the borderless buttons side by side will workout ?

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="Criar Contan"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@color/background_grey" />

<Button
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Entrar"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

Comment: Kinda workout, but the buttons lost the click animation

Comment: just add android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" to each button